# Visual Studio 2010 Class Diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hello is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 to auto generate a function call flow diagram for an solution with multiple projects in it? I mean what function from which class in which project is calling other functions from the same project or different class or project.

I will really appreciate help with this. I have to dive into a really complicated project with no documentation.

Comment: http://modeling.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it might depend on the version of visual studio 2010 you have.

If you want a sequence diagram: Right-click anywhere in the method definition, and then click Generate Sequence Diagram. I'm pretty sure this is Ultimate only. MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317485.aspx

If you're talking about seeing what function calling is going on, you can select the function name and right click then click view call hierarchy it will show all the functions that call it or it calls. You can also generate a sequence diagram via the function name.

You can also create a class diagram. Either right click on the solution/project/etc->Class Diagram or go to Architecture->Generate Dependency Graph->Class Diagram to make a class dependency diagram for the solution you have open, then you can click the down arrow on a class to view how the functions in that class interact.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't find the option for Architecture. I am using VS 2010 Professional.

Comment: I googled it, and it is available for Ultimate version only. thanks for the help in any case. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another way: right click on the projects/namespace/class, and then choose the "View class diagram".

Comment: Useful, but as far as I understand the question, not what was asked for.